# Given $\nabla f(c)\ne 0$, is there exactly one and only one unit vector $u$ in $\mathbb R^n$ such that $\|\nabla f(c)\|=|f'(c;u)|$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f$ be real valued and  differentiable at a point $c$ in $\mathbb R^n$ and assume that $\|\nabla f(c)\|\ne 0$. Prove that there is one and only one unit vector $u$ in $\mathbb R^n$ such that $\|\nabla f(c)\|=|f'(c;u)|$, and that this is the unit vector for which $|f'(c;u)|$ has its maximum value.

I think that there are exactly two such unit vectors. Following is the working behind my conclusion:

Since $f$ is differentiable at $c$, the following holds for any unit vector $u$.

$$f'(c;u)=\nabla f(c)\cdot u=\|\nabla f(c)\|\cos\theta,$$ where $\theta$ can be regarded as the angle between $\nabla f(c)$ (non zero vector) and the unit vector $u$.

It follows that $|f'(c;u)|=\|\nabla f(c)\||\cos\theta|$ and the equality happens only if $|\cos \theta|=1$ that is, if $\theta =0$ or $\pi$. That is, if $u$ is parallel or anti-parallel to $\nabla f(c)$. That is, $u=\pm \frac{\nabla f(c)}{\|\nabla f(c)\|}$. So $u$ has exactly two possibilities.

I want to know why $u$ then is unique. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Where is this from? Perhaps there is a typo, if you are looking for $u$ such that $\|\nabla f(c)\| = f'(c;u)$ then only one of them works

Comment: @CalvinKhor: This is from exercise no. $12.11$ from Apostol's Mathematical analysis, 2nd Edition.

Comment: Alas :) There is no errata or newer edition for this book. In any case, your reasoning is correct. If you must continue using this book, perhaps you can write an errata yourself and release it for future readers!

Comment: @CalvinKhor: Thanks a lot for the feedback. :-)

Comment: No problem; for some reason I typed an example and didn’t send the comment. But it is easy to check that there are two $u$ directly for $f(x)=x_1=\binom10\cdot x$